# When milk is poured into cereal, what is it?

Tags: milk

Is it a broth, a sauce, a beverage, or other? this was a question posed to me and I have clue how to answer this.

Answer (score 2):

It is none of those. If pushed to provide a word I would call the milk an *accompaniment* to the cereal, but I don't see any good reason there should be a general word to apply here.